Как осуществить запуск браузеров в фоновом режиме через Selenium?
У меня есть написанная на Java + Selenium программа для автоматизации браузера. К сожалению, по некоторым причинам не могу использовать headless режим.
Хотелось бы понять, как использовать браузер в свернутом (или перекрытом) режиме?
Если сейчас запускать программу через IDE, то я могу делать с браузером любые действия: сворачивать, разворачивать, перекрывать, — что угодно; действия в нём не перестанут выполняться.
Но если я запускаю программу через jar или bat-файл, то браузер моментально умирает. Работает только если его видно на экране.
Никаких ответов по этому вопросу в Интернете не могу уже больше года найти...

Помогло использование стороннего приложения Actual Window Manager, там можно привязать окно к рабочему столу, и даже накладывать браузеры друг на друга

public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "path_to_driver");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless");     
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
    }

Вы не будете видеть окон, установив аргумент headless и они будут работать в фоновом режиме
